# необходимо создать сервер java

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, сервер, сокет

Необходимо создать сервер java который каждые 20 мс отсылает пакеты, а клиент каждые 20мс принимает. Также посоветуйте как эти данные сохранять в бд с такой же периодичностью.

вот мой код клиента:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        // здесь обязательно нужно указать порт к которому привязывается сервер.
        int serverPort = 5050;
        // это IP-адрес компьютера, где исполняется наша серверная программа.
        String address = "192.168.1.15";

        // Здесь указан адрес того самого компьютера
        // где будет исполняться и клиент.
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(address, serverPort);

            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

            //String str="hello";
            DataOutputStream out1 = new DataOutputStream(os);
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

            int r;
            while ((r = in.read()) >= 0)
                System.out.printf("%02X ", r);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем каждые 20мс? Может отправлять и принимать только тогда, когда есть что отправлять?

Comment: На прием данных я бы использовал Listner of the socket

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780614/8992586